# c# linq let statement broken into pieces with a view model

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Alrighty so I am trying to build a linq statement using query syntax. I expect to have more filter criteria functions, and utlimately multiple configuration that include specific criterias. The flow here works

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Shoe>> GetShoesByCriteria()
{
    IQueryable<Shoe> shoes = FilteredContext;
    shoes = FilterShoesByInsurance()
    return shoes.ToList();
}

private IQueryable<Shoe> FilterShoesByInsurance(IQueryable<Shoe> shoes,List<Guid> Insurer)
{
    var x = (from s in shoes
             let shoeInsurer = _insuranceContext.Context.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.ShoeID= s.ID
              && Insurer.Contains(s.Insurer.ID)
             )
             
             where shoeInsurer != null
             select m
             );

    return x;
}
```

I would like to, at the very end, have a view model ShoeViewModel that has the shoe insurer hydrated on it.

Is there any way to build iqueryables like this on the go while hydrating a view model? I would really like to avoid going to ienumerable and inducing multiple round trips, additionally I would like to avoid having to write the logic for getting an insurer twice

Comment: I should add that FIlteredContext is an Iqueryable that through applicationdbcontext would give me access to the Shoes table

Comment: Switch from query syntax to fluent/lambda syntax and you can daisy chain `.Where()` method calls onto an `IQueryable` as long as the filters are ANDed together. For something more complicated, you need to use something like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and Predicate Builder or roll your own equivalent.

Comment: is there a way to daisy chain the where and use let/predicate statements? I dont think linq kit will help me here either.  I am able to daisy chain my methods with individual predicate statements but when you select, the data is lost unless if you bind it to a view model. Once in a view model, how do you run another .where and select?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the data is lost". As for `let`, that translates to a `Select` to a new anonymous object with the `let` range variable definition added: `from a in abc let b = a.name select b` translates to something like `abc.Select(a => new { a, b = a.name }).Select(ab => ab.b)`

Comment: If that is true, I think this is exactly what I need. Thank you!!!

Comment: FYI you can use LINQPad to view the translation of query syntax to fluent/lambda for queries.

Comment:  that is amazing

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using lambda expressions, you could use something like the following:

```
bool requireMultipleInsurers = true;
List<Guid> insureres = new(){};
// to do add insurers


var _query = (from tbl in _dbContext.Shoes
              .Include(x => x.Insurer)
              select tbl);

if(insurers.Any())
{
    _query = _query.Where(x => x.Insurer.Any(y => insurers.Contains(y.Id)));
}

if(requireMultipleInsurers)
{
    _query = _query.Where(x => x.Insurer.Count() > 1);
}

var _results = await _query.ToListAsync();
```

This way multiple clauses can be strung along given a set of criteria, and the query is only run when ToListAsync() is called.

Comment: does adding the include make the query join even if the data is not returned? The nice part of lets is that if you dont use the predicate in the query it excludes the SQL code which I am hoping to leverage . I am not sure if this would do the same, and I worry about scalability as I include more and more tables to the configuration

Comment: If you just need to filter on related entities, than just use them in the Where clause and it won't return the related data.  If you need the related data, then add it with the Include clause.  The Include clause can also be conditionally added if sometimes you would need to include related data.